# Using a FilePath when interfacing with a function that uses fopen on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, character-encoding, filepath, ffi

I'm using the FFI to work with a portable C library. However, I'm running into issues when trying to use some of the library functions that use `fopen` internally, probably due to filename encoding.

GHC offers some mechanisms that can be used to control the encoding used with functions like `pushCString`. E.g., the following code should push a Haskell `String` value as nul-terminated C string using the encoding used by the file system:

```hs
import qualified GHC.Foreign as GHC
import qualified GHC.IO.Encoding as GHC

main =
  encoding <- GHC.getFileSystemEncoding
  GHC.pushCString encoding "my example"
```

This appears to work well on Unix-like systems, but not on Windows: My program cannot find files that contain umlauts.

The documentation of `getFileSystemEncoding` comes with the warning that hints at the problem.

> On Windows, this encoding *should not* be used if possible because the use of code pages is deprecated: Strings should be retrieved via the "wide" W-family of UTF-16 APIs instead

But this gives no info on how to deal with a filepath that will be passed to a foreign function.

##### Minimal example

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign.C (CString)
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr, nullPtr)
import qualified GHC.Foreign as GHC
import qualified GHC.IO.Encoding as GHC

filename = "Ümlauts.txt"

main = do
  writeFile filename "content"  -- ensure file exists
  fsEncoding <- GHC.getFileSystemEncoding
  GHC.withCString fsEncoding filename $ \fscpath -> do
    handle <- greeting_fopen fscpath
    if handle == nullPtr
      then error $ "Could not open file " ++ filename
      else do
        putStrLn "file opened successfully"

-- Library function that uses fopen internally
foreign import ccall "greeting.c greeting_fopen"
  greeting_fopen :: CString -> IO (Ptr ())
```

where `greeting.c` contains

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *greeting_fopen (const char *filename) {
  printf("Hello, now trying to open %s\n", filename);
  return fopen (filename, "r");
}
```

Running `ghc --make greeting.c main.hs` and executing the resulting binary succeeds on Linux, but fails on Windows due to the file not being found.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows documentation for [fopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen) states:

> The `fopen` function opens the file that is specified by `filename`. By default, a narrow filename string is interpreted using the ANSI codepage (`CP_ACP`).

Therefore, that's the code page that must be used to encode the filename when it is passed to the library function. We can't pass `CPACP` (or `CP_ACP`) as the argument for [`System.IO.mkTextEncoding`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:mkTextEncoding), as that function only supports numerical code pages like "CP1252".

However, CP_ACP is available as code page `0`, so we can use

```hs
fsEncoding <- System.IO.mkTextEncoding "CP0"
```

Of course, this won't work with Linux, so we need some ugly CPP code like

```hs
#if defined(mingw32_HOST_OS)
  fsEncoding <- mkTextEncoding "CP0"
#else
  fsEncoding <- getFileSystemEncoding
#endif
```

The code may still fail if the filename cannot be represented in the ANSI codepage, but that seems to be an unfixable limitation.

---

The use of "CP0" is a bit of a hack; for completeness, here's some code that uses `getACP` from the Windows API to get the right codepage.

```hs
import Data.Word (Word32 (..))
import GHC.IO.Encoding.CodePage (codePageEncoding)

foreign import ccall unsafe "windows.h GetACP"
    getACP :: IO Word32

getFileSystemEncoding =
  codePageEncoding <$> getACP
```